# how to send function error report through email in django

Tags: python, django

I have to implement paystation payment gateway in my project, this gateway response in two ways after the transaction one on return url and other on POST url, post url works on the backend as it works in all other payment gateways, It returns all the payment related response on POST url, It returns the result in XML format.

I want to send this response on my email, so that i can check the response parameters, so i am using this code.

```
def payment_post(request):
    responseData = xmltodict.parse(request.POST)
    msg = EmailMultiAlternatives('Post Parameters', responseData, 'exampleFrom@gmail.com', ['exampleTo@gmail.com'])
    msg.send()
```

Its not sending me any details on my email id, but when i use this code

```
msg = EmailMultiAlternatives('Post Parameters', 'Testing data', 'exampleFrom@gmail.com', ['exampleTo@gmail.com'])
msg.send()
```

It sends me the mail with 'testing data' as mail content and 'POST parameters' as subject, so it means there are some issues in parsing xml or i am not getting any post data in response.

So i want to check the error, is there any way i can get the error details for this , can i send the error details on my email id ?

Edit:- I am getting this xml response

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<InitiationRequestResponse>
<Username>
605002
</Username>
<RequestIP>
203.118.134.77
</RequestIP>
<RequestUserAgent/>
<RequestHttpReferrer/>
<PaymentRequestTime>2008-10-02 15:59:29</PaymentRequestTime>
<DigitalOrder>
https://payments.paystation.co.nz/hosted/?hk=KBzTIBy5oYEI
</DigitalOrder>
<DigitalOrderTime>2008-10-02 15:59:30</DigitalOrderTime>
<DigitalReceiptTime/>
<PaystationTransactionID>0000000466-01</PaystationTransactionID>
</InitiationRequestResponse>
```

Thanks

Comment: is responseData a string or something which quacks like a string?

Comment: response is in xml and i am parsing it in disctionary, actually the documentation is in php but i have to convert it in python, so lots of problem i am facing.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you need an `XML` string need to `xmltodict` library `parse` function,
first you need to get the `XML` string from `POST`, needed code change is similar to below code, points to be noted,

- here POST['data'] means the key of the form you are using
- if you are sending the data from HTTP Body, you need to replace
  request.POST with  request.body.decode('utf-8')
- request.FILES['filename'].read(), if you are uploading a file ( xml file ) where form key is 'filename'.

  ```
  import json
  def payment_post(request):
      responseData = xmltodict.parse(request.POST['data'])
      responseString = json.dumps(responseData) # or you can use just str(responseData) if you have simple data values
      msg = EmailMultiAlternatives('Post Parameters', responseString, 'exampleFrom@gmail.com', ['exampleTo@gmail.com'])
      msg.send()
  ```

if the thing is getting the `POST` form keys & values as dict, request.POST is QueryDict object not what you need, for that the code can be changed as

```
def payment_post(request):
    responseData = xmltodict.parse(request.POST.dict())
    msg = EmailMultiAlternatives('Post Parameters', responseData, 'exampleFrom@gmail.com', ['exampleTo@gmail.com'])
    msg.send()
```

Comment: Plz check in edit, this response i am getting as xml response, what i have to  write for "data" in request.POST['data'] ?

Comment: I think you are thinking request.POST is dict with posted data, but its not,
check my updated post @Pankaj

Comment: I used this one also but now its giving me error :- must be string or read-only buffer, not dict

Comment: @Pankaj add tracebacks/exception you got in question